# React Redux Connect wrap component

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Im learning react and the instructor creates components as in Code 1 where as I create the function as in Code 2. How do we wrap code 2 within Redux Connect()?

**Code 1**

```
const Header = ({ currentUser }) => (
  <div className='header'>
    <Link className='logo-container' to='/'>
      <Logo className='logo' />
    </Link>
    
    
  </div>
);
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  currentUser: state.user.currentUser
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Header);
```

**Code 2**

```
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';


export default function Header({currentUser}) {
    return (
        <div className='header'>
            <Link className='logo-container' to="/">
                <Logo className='logo' />
            </Link>
            <div className='options'>
                <Link className='option' to="/shop">
                    SHOP
                </Link>
                <Link className='option' to="/shop">
                    CONTACT
                </Link>
                {
                    currentUser ?
                    <div className='option' onClick={() => auth.signOut()}>SIGN OUT</div>
                    :
                    <Link className='option' to="/signin">SIGN IN</Link>
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this should work:

```
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';


export default connect(mapStateToProps)(function({currentUser})) {
    return (
        <div className='header'>
            <Link className='logo-container' to="/">
                <Logo className='logo' />
            </Link>
            <div className='options'>
                <Link className='option' to="/shop">
                    SHOP
                </Link>
                <Link className='option' to="/shop">
                    CONTACT
                </Link>
                {
                    currentUser ?
                    <div className='option' onClick={() => auth.signOut()}>SIGN OUT</div>
                    :
                    <Link className='option' to="/signin">SIGN IN</Link>
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Then, you can import it at any file using this line:

```
import AnyNameYouWant from './Header.js';
```

If we would have exported it like this:

```
export const Header = connect(mapStateToProps)(function({currentUser})) {...
```

Then you would have needed to change your import statements to this:

```
import { Header } from './Header.js';
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: what about the component name Header?

Comment: When you default export on one line, the name doesn't hane any impact on your code. You can import this component with any name you want.

Comment: Thank you for revisiting and explaining in detail. Really appreciate.